# use POST to retrieve specified item from DB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

imagine this scenario, I want to update a book's detail. so I should have that book id, I do like this

```
router.get('/edit/:book_id', function(req, res) {
    Products.getBookById(req.params.book_id, function(err,product){
      //render
    });
});

<a href="edit/3434050348984585646">update this book</a>
```

I'm done, my flow is correct but my only concern is the the url is not nice, like localhost:8000/books/update/3434050348984585646

How can I hide the url? how to use POST in my case?

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `:bookId` from your route definition, and change your link to a form:

JS

```
router.get('/edit', function(req, res) {
    Products.getBookById(req.params.book_id, function(err,product){
      //render
    });
});
```

HTML

```
<form action="edit" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="book_id" value="3434050348984585646">
    <input type="submit" value="Update this book">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to use the well known [POST/Redirect/GET pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) (which has the advantage of preventing double POSTs).

The advantage is that you do not have to use URL parameters (which may well have security impacts) or have to deal with hidden form fields.

So you receive a POST as usual, and after processing the parameters, you send a redirect message to the client, either with a code of `302 "Found"` or  (preferred) with a `303 "See Other"` and the URL you want to redirect to. While sending a 302 *may* cause a client to use GET instead of the original request method to call the URL you redirected to (it usually does), the 303 code explicitly instructs the client to use GET, no matter what the original request method was.